# Call angular js function on html tag load

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to call one angular js function using controller. I am using code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DevPortal</title>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="devportal">
    <div ng-include="'templates/login_menu.html'"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('devportal', []);
app.controller('AppController', function($scope, $http) {
    return{
        getuserloginmenu : function(){$http.get('/getuserloginmenu').then(function(response){$scope.loginmenu=response.data;})},
        getuserloginmenu1 : function(){$http.get('/getuserloginmenu1').then(function(response){$scope.loginmenu1=response.data;})}
    };
});
```

login_menu.html

```
<div ng-controller="AppController as ctrl">
    <div on-init="ctrl.getuserloginmenu()">
        <p ng-repeat="menu in loginmenu">{{menu}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My `rest` service is working properly and returns String array. I am not able to call/get the rest service data in html.

Comment: Do you get any console errors?

Comment: No any console error. Here my rest service itself is not getting called, not sure why.

Comment: what is on-init? Also your controller looks strange - not sure if its work, but looks unusual.

Comment: Oha! Thanks. It should be ng-init. Now I am able to get the data.I was stuck from last one day ;( thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems legit, the only thing making noise (at least for me) is the `on-init` you added to call the function. I think that's the problem.
Try

```
<div ng-controller="AppController as ctrl">
    <div ng-init="ctrl.getuserloginmenu()">
        <p ng-repeat="menu in loginmenu">{{menu}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And maybe.. To keep it clean: Change the syntax of the controller (even if it works)

```
var app = angular.module('devportal', []);
app.controller('AppController', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.getuserloginmenu = function(){$http.get('/getuserloginmenu').then(function(response){$scope.loginmenu=response.data;})};
        $scope.getuserloginmenu1 = function(){$http.get('/getuserloginmenu1').then(function(response){$scope.loginmenu1=response.data;})};
});
```

---

**Edit:** 
That's a missuse of ng-init. I'll leave the documentation of Angular for that matter
https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-init.asp
But shortly, you want `$scope.loginmenu` to populate. You don't need to wait until the div loads. You can populate `$scope.loginmenu` right away when the controller inits.

View

```
<div ng-controller="AppController as ctrl">
        <div>
            <p ng-repeat="menu in loginmenu">{{menu}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('devportal', []);
app.controller('AppController', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.getuserloginmenu = function(){$http.get('/getuserloginmenu').then(function(response){$scope.loginmenu=response.data;})};
        $scope.getuserloginmenu1 = function(){$http.get('/getuserloginmenu1').then(function(response){$scope.loginmenu1=response.data;})};
        $scope.getuserloginmenu();
});
```

Comment: This is **not** what ng-init is for

Comment: I don't have enough information to agree with your statement... I mean, 
 you're probably right. But i need more context. What does "getuserloginmenu()"? We don't know

Comment: It makes no difference. Just call that method in controller instead of using ng-init

Comment: @charlietfl tell me your thoughts on the edit please :)

Comment: Only bug is OP is using `Controller as` vs $scope